# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling', pandas

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

This is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
from pylab import mpl,plt
import quandl as q

plt.style.use('ggplot')
mpl.rcParams['font.family']='serif'


q.ApiConfig.api_key='7QRLThQTiHp5Xp-tFlk'

d=q.get('BCHAIN/MKPRU') 

d['SMA']=d['Value'].rolling(100).mean()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

I am using pandas 0.18.1

Comment: pandas 1.2.5 runs with no issue after getting an API key

Comment: also works with 1.3.0.  0.18.1 is a very out of date version of pandas....